# Проблема с отображением границ выпадающего списка в Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: bootstrap

Я сейчас работаю с проектом на Boostrap 3, и столкнулся с проблемой отображения нижней и левой границы выпадающего списка: отсутствует либо лева либо нижняя граница списка (в зависимости от версии Windows 10).

[image: Bottom border is missing]

**Детали:**

- Версия Bootstrap - 3.3.7;
- Версия браузера - Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (64-bit);
- Версия ОС - Windows 10 Pro.

На GitHub Bootstrap-а ребята предлагают мигрировать на 4-ю версию, но в рамках данного проекта, мы этого сделать не сможем, уж очень трудозатратное решение. Ссылка на ошибку с GitHub -
 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22633.

Возможно, у кого-то есть идеи, как можно быстро пофиксить данную ошибку ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это стандартный выпадающий список <select>? Один из вариантов - сделать кастомное выпадающее окно со списком <option>-ов из этого <select>-а

Comment: Да, все правильно, это стандартный <select class="form-control"><option></option></select>. Спасибо, кастомный dropdown - это хорошая идея, но пока что, ее не рассматриваем.